# is WPF application works in all operating systems(windows)?

Tags: wpf

Is WPF application works in all windows operating systems or not.
which is the best way to OS compatibility WPF apps.

Answer (score 2):

WPF is part of the .Net Framework starting from version 3.0

It will run on any OSes that support the (Microsoft version) of the .Net Framework that you're targetting.

Answer (score 0):

WPF can work with any Windows Versions starting from XP you just have to make sure that the .net framework your application is buit with is installed on the os.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WPF works on all the windows OS.
Check

> [WPF apps and operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838702/wpf-apps-and-operating-system)